# How to get text from dynamically created buttons?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want my buttons when i click on them to return the text attribute of them.

I've used a for loop to dynamically create the buttons but when i do this the btn variable gets stuck on the last created button meaning every button returns the same text value.

```py
listWords = ("Car","Train","Bus","Bike")
var = 0
def getdef():
    print(btn['text'])
for word in listWords:
    btn = Button(window, text=word,command=getdef)
    btn.grid(column=var, row=0)
    var = var + 1
```

This code  produces 4 buttons: 
[Image of buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIAXw.png)

However no matter what button i press btn['text'] will always return Bike. I want the output to be that of the button itself for example when i click car i want btn['text'] to return car.

Comment: do you know how to use `list` and keep many elements (ie. Buttons) on list ?

Comment: Remove `, command=getdef` and change to `btn.bind('<Button-1>', text)`. Output with `def text(event): print(event.widget['text'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lambda` in `command=` to assign function with argument - `word` - and function has to get this argument - `def get_text(text)`

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_text(text):
    print(text)

list_words = ("Car","Train","Bus","Bike")

var = 0

root = tk.Tk()

for word in list_words:
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=word, command=lambda txt=word:get_text(txt))
    btn.grid(column=var, row=0)
    var += 1

root.mainloop()
```

Instead of `word` you can send `btn` to function so you can get text from button but also change text on button or change its color, etc.

But it need little different method

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_widget(widget):
    print(widget["text"])
    widget["text"] = "DONE"
    widget["bg"] = "green"

list_words = ("Car","Train","Bus","Bike")

var = 0

root = tk.Tk()

for word in list_words:
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=word)
    btn["command"] = lambda widget=btn:get_widget(widget)
    btn.grid(column=var, row=0)
    var += 1

root.mainloop()
```

You can also use `bind('<Button-1>', callback)` to assing click to Button or other Windget and it will run function with argument `event` which gives access to  clicked widget - `event.widget`

```
import tkinter as tk

def get_event(event):
    print(event.widget["text"])
    event.widget["text"] = "DONE"
    event.widget["bg"] = "green"

list_words = ("Car","Train","Bus","Bike")

var = 0

root = tk.Tk()

for word in list_words:
    btn = tk.Button(root, text=word)
    btn.bind('<Button-1>', get_event)
    btn.grid(column=var, row=0)
    var += 1

root.mainloop()
```