# Can I get the text on a button when changed after clicking on it in Python?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Here is an example of what I am trying to convey:

```py
from tkinter import *

def start():
    print("Start")
    B1.pack_forget()
    B2.pack()


def stop():
    B2.pack_forget()
    B1.pack()

root = Tk()
root.title("TestWin")

B1 = Button(root, text='start', command=start)
B1.pack()
B2 = Button(root, text='stop', command=stop)

root.mainloop()
```

Now I want to use *if* logic to get the name of the button currently packed. And it could look something like:

> if <*button_text_keyword*> == 'start' then print('Start') elif <*button_text_keyword*> == 'stop' then print("Stop").

Can this be done??? Or Do I have to type a long code in order to achieve that???

Please suggest a good method to do what I want or rectify me.

Comment: You can use a global variable to hold the reference of currently packed button and set it in `start()` and `stop()` functions.

Comment: Or you can combine the two buttons into one button and just update its text when it is clicked.  Then you don't need to call `pack_forget()` and `pack()`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-to-get-text-from-dynamically-created-buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598418)

Comment: Thanks @acw1668 I got that global variable thing

Comment: Thanks @stovfl that method too was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to be clear, if the goal is just to print whatever text the button is showing, the simplest is to just have separate `command` functions, as you have done.  It's then explicitly clear which button was there at the time of the click.  So by this I mean, just add a `print` statement in the `stop` function.

But assuming there is a more nuanced situation where you actually need to determine what is packed in a different part of the program, this is an example **based on what @acw1668 suggested** in the comments:

```
from tkinter import *

packed = 'B1'

def start():
    global packed
    B1.pack_forget()
    B2.pack()
    packed = 'B2'

def stop():
    global packed
    B2.pack_forget()
    B1.pack()
    packed = 'B1'

def check():
    if packed == 'B1':
        print("Start")
    elif packed == 'B2':
        print("Stop")

root = Tk()
root.title("TestWin")

B1 = Button(root, text='start', command=start)
B1.pack(side=TOP)
B2 = Button(root, text='stop', command=stop)
B3 = Button(root, text='check', command=check)
B3.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

The new button ("check") determines what button is packed, based on the flag `packed` (just to note, if you instead wrap the application in `class` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application)), you could avoid having to use `global`).

The above is more than sufficient, but if you actually want to check the button object itself, you can **check the packed elements in a Frame with `pack_slaves()`**:

```
from tkinter import *

def start():
    B1.pack_forget()
    B2.pack()

def stop():
    B2.pack_forget()
    B1.pack()

def check():
    global button_frame
    button = button_frame.pack_slaves()[0]
    text = (button.cget('text'))
    if text == 'start':
        print('Start')
    elif text == 'stop':
        print('Stop')

root = Tk()
root.title("TestWin")

button_frame = Frame(root,)
button_frame.pack(side=TOP)

B1 = Button(button_frame, text='start', command=start)
B1.pack()
B2 = Button(button_frame, text='stop', command=stop)
B3 = Button(root, text='check', command=check)
B3.pack(side=BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

This second example sounds more similar to the logic you described; i.e. find object corresponding to the pressed button, then get its text using `cget`, and route that to determine what is printed.  Note that this example finds the button widget by using `button = button_frame.pack_slaves()[0]`, so there is an assumption that there will only be clearly one button packed in `button_frame`.

**Another option** would be to use [`bind`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) to program the button's effects, rather than the `command` parameter.  You could then create a function like `check` in the above example to bind to both buttons, and you could use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4373296/13386979) to get the pressed widget (and then check it's identity/text, determine what to print,  etc....).

Comment: Thanks @Tom both the methods worked great and I discovered correct usage of two more tkinter methods

Comment: Thanks @Tom both the logics work great
That if logic thing that I wrote was just the shortest possible example I could give otherwise I have different usage for it

Answer (score 0):

## If you want that on clicking the button your button text will get change then you try #this

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("title")

def start():
    #for changing text on button
    button_name.config(text="new text on button")

B1 = Button(root, text='start', command=start)
B1.pack()
```

Comment: No only changing the name is not what I wanted, that I did in the code that I provided in the question anyways thanks for trying to help but I got the correct answer